# Issue with third party Google Analytics sdk

Tags: php, google-analytics, xampp, composer-php, measurement-protocol

I have code which works above the php 5

its actually GA Library, here is its github project.

I have cloned the project [theiconic/php-ga-measurement-protocol](https://github.com/theiconic/php-ga-measurement-protocol)

Since I am new to PHP, I have no idea where to put this code, Please help me here this project should be installed via composer via code

```
{
    "require": {
        "theiconic/php-ga-measurement-protocol": "^2.0"
    }
}
```

After this step I need to create a file something.php and I need to put the code below, I am having problem on locating autoload.php on my server, Please look at the code below to understand what i am saying.

```
<?php
        //grab the data that Calendly sent in the webhook and store it in a variable called $objCalendlySubmission...
        $objCalendlySubmission = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));

        //We've passed the Google client_id in Calendly's placeholder for utm_term. Feel free to pass it differently, this is just an example
        if(property_exists($objCalendlySubmission->payload->tracking, 'utm_term') && !empty($objCalendlySubmission->payload->tracking->utm_term)) {
            $strPageViewed = 'calendly_conversion.html'; // We use different page names depending on what type of event was scheduled via Calendly
            sendGoogleAnalyticsPageView($objCalendlySubmission->payload->tracking->utm_term, $strPageViewed);
        }

        function sendGoogleAnalyticsPageView($strGAClientId, $strURL) {
            require_once '/path_to_composer/composer/vendor/autoload.php'; //loads the PHP library for the "Google Analytics Measurement Protocol” **I dont know where is it located exactly on my xampp server, Please guide me here**
            $analytics = new TheIconic\Tracking\GoogleAnalytics\Analytics(true); //you may have to adjust this path based on your setup **please help me here**

            $analytics
                ->setProtocolVersion('1')
                ->setTrackingId('YOUR-GA-UA-ID-GOES-HERE')
                ->setClientId($strGAClientId)
                ->setDocumentLocationUrl($strURL);

            $analytics->sendPageview(); 
        }
        ?>
```

In the above code towards middle line

```
require_once '/path_to_composer/composer/vendor/autoload.php'; //loads the PHP library for the "Google Analytics Measurement Protocol”
```

I dont know where is it located exactly on my xampp server, Please guide me here

```
$analytics = new TheIconic\Tracking\GoogleAnalytics\Analytics(true); //you may have to adjust this path based on your setup
```

Here is the image of Project folder
[image]

Project structure Part 2 
[image]

Comment: Have you consider commenting on the project page.  I think you will have better luck contacting the third party developer directly rather than hoping someone uses their library here.   You may also want to note that it doesn't look like anyone is actively developing on that library.

Comment: I tried contacting them, they are not responding

Comment: Are you having any issue when your require the autoload ? Does any errors show up ?

Comment: @UlrichDohou I am having issues to get the location of autload.php on server

Comment: Can you share image of your project structure ?

Comment: @UlrichDohou Please check my updated question, Its a shared hosting